# Error when trying to register a task with task scheduler (Win7)

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

To enable my application to startup with admin rights at user login, I use a task in task scheduler. And it works fine. Mostly. Now I've received bug reports saying that this fails:

```
rootFolder->RegisterTaskDefinition( _bstr_t(name.toWideCharPointer()), task,              
   TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE, _variant_t(L"Builtin\\Administrators"), _variant_t(), 
   TASK_LOGON_GROUP, _variant_t(L""), &registeredTask) -> 0x80070534
```

0x80070534 seems to mean "No mapping between account names and security IDs was done". I'm following (pretty much verbatim) the example at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381911(v=VS.85).aspx

Ideas what has gone wrong, and how to fix it ? The application has manifest set so the user needs to be admin to run it.

Question: The "Builtin\\Administrators" group, it is language dependent, isn't it ? I think that the user in question might have a non-english Windows 7. If so I imagine it would work better with specifying "S-1-5-32-544" instead ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330 )

Update: So the explicit call looks like:

```
rootFolder->RegisterTaskDefinition(
            _bstr_t(name.toWideCharPointer()),
            task,
            TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE,
            _variant_t(L"S-1-5-32-544"),    // Language independent "BUILTIN\Administrators" 
            _variant_t(),
            TASK_LOGON_GROUP,
            _variant_t(L""),
            &registeredTask)
```

Make sure that the application is executed with elevated privileges, otherwise that call will fail.

Comment: Oh... the CoInitializeSecurity call before returns RPC_E_TOO_LATE. I do call it, with other parameters (RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT instead of RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_PRIVACY), if that should have any bearing on the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending some time, I've seen that more modifications than just `_variant_t(L"S-1-5-32-544")` are needed to make this ["Logon Trigger Example (C++)" example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381911(v=VS.85).aspx) work.

All the details can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45244583/1422096).

Answer (score 3):

The problem indeed lies in the parameter `_variant_t(L"Builtin\\Administrators")`, which is hard-coded to English version of Windows. By using the language agnostic security identifier "S-1-5-32-544" ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330 ), the problem is resolved.

Update: So the explicit call looks like:

```
rootFolder->RegisterTaskDefinition(
            _bstr_t(name.toWideCharPointer()),
            task,
            TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE,
            _variant_t(L"S-1-5-32-544"),    // Language independent "BUILTIN\Administrators" 
            _variant_t(),
            TASK_LOGON_GROUP,
            _variant_t(L""),
            &registeredTask)
```

Make sure that the application is executed with elevated privileges, otherwise the call will fail.

Comment: I'm close to a solution thanks to this answer @Robert! How do you use S-1-5-32-544? I tried `_variant_t(L"S-1-5-32-544")` but it still fails...

Comment: Is your application running at elevated privilege ? That call needs admin privs to succeed with that parameter.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: If UAC is disabled (lowest cursor in the UAC options), it should work directly without doing anything about privs ?

Comment: Hmm... yes, it should indeed, given that the user is part of the admin group. What error code does the call return ?

Comment: But still, the app needs to be executed with elevated privileges. Disabling UAC only means it will fail silently (if not running elevated).

Comment: I reenabled UAC in default mode, I have taken [this code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381911(v=vs.85).aspx) modified with your advice in this current answer (`_variant_t(L"S-1-5-32-544")`), and [here is the full final code](https://pastebin.com/mEzpMJx5). In VC++, Project Settings > Linker > Manifest, I have enabled `requireAdminstrator`. When I build and run, I get the dialog asking for Admin privs, I say yes... And result: still the 0x80070534 error :(  I had the following to have done everything needed...

Comment: Maybe could you share a VC++ project (i have 2013) showing such a TaskScheduler creation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149677/discussion-between-robert-and-basj).