# C++ Logon task schedule Error: No Mapping between account names and security ids was done

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to write a windows Logon trigger task using C++ on Windows 7.

I am following [this microsoft tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

But I am facing problem in saving the task to root folder.
Here:

```
//  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Save the task in the root folder.
    IRegisteredTask *pRegisteredTask = NULL;

    hr = pRootFolder->RegisterTaskDefinition(
            _bstr_t( wszTaskName ),
            pTask,
            TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE, 
            _variant_t(L"Builtin\\Administrators"), 
            _variant_t(), 
            TASK_LOGON_GROUP,
            _variant_t(L""),
            &pRegisteredTask);
```

Where the `hr` is getting error :  ***No Mapping between account names and security ids was done***

I also tried replacing `_variant_t(L"Builtin\\Administrators")` with `_variant_t(L"S-1-5-32-544")` to NULL out language hard coding issue, still No luck.

How can I make it work?

Comment: Try creating an explicit BSTR (using, say [`_bstr_t`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthfhkd6.aspx), and `_variant_t()` for the sddl (rather than `_variant_t(L"")`.

Comment: If that fails, use     `CreateWellKnownSid(WinBuiltinAdministratorsSid, NULL, &sid, &dwBytes);` to create the administrator SID, followed by `ConvertSidToStringSid( &sid, &psz);` to convert that to string form.

Comment: Hi Eric, Tried both the options you suggested. Unfortunately none worked for me. Getting the same error either way.

Comment: Looking over the various usages, I suspect the problem is actually in the definition of `pTask`, which you haven't provided.  In particular, for group accounts,  the code I have retrieves the `IPrincipal` and sets the `RunLevel` and `GroupId` properties on that.

Comment: Can you give me or point me to a working copy of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the demo code you have is XP-era, and hasn't been updated to match the Vista/Win7 rules.

I updated the sample to set the LUA settings after setting the logon trigger, and it seems to work:

```
    hr = pLogonTrigger->put_UserId(_bstr_t(L"DOMAIN\username"));
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot add user ID to logon trigger: %x", hr);
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }


    //*** NEW**** Set the LUA settings
    CComPtr<IPrincipal>         pPrincipal;

    hr = pTask->get_Principal(&pPrincipal);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pPrincipal->put_RunLevel(TASK_RUNLEVEL_LUA);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pPrincipal->put_GroupId(_bstr_t(L"Builtin\\Administrators"));
    }
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot set runlevel/groupid: %x", hr);
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }
```

If you need it to run on XP, then it's likely that the `get_Principal` call will fail, so let that failure through.

Comment: Added the LUA setting block. Still not working. same error. :(
Can you share the full code that is working for you?

Comment: @smilepleeeaz You *did* change `pLogonTrigger->put_UserId(_bstr_t(L"DOMAIN\username"));` to have a real domain & username, right?

Comment: Oops. I didn't. changing it did scheduled the task. Even without LUA settings. Oh God, Why!!!

Comment: But the whole point is not to prompt user for username , password.. how do we get that ?

Comment: Assuming you just want the current user, then [`GetUserNameEx(NameSamCompatible, pchBuf, &cchBuf)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724435(v=vs.85).aspx) should do the trick.

Comment: Well it was just my bad, but you sure helped me enough to figure it out, so thanks, and you deserve the bounty reward. :)

Comment: BTW , is there a way we can make repetitive logon task?

Comment: @smilepleeeaz Not sure what you mean by 'repetitive logon task'; consider ITrigger::put_Repetition; this is defined for all triggers, including logon triggers.

Comment: @Basj Shouldn't you be commenting on *that* answer, not here?  Further, the next answer suggests passing null, which is documented to be the local computer.

Answer (score 6):

## A definitive solution to creation of a Task Scheduler task on Windows startup

(with Administrator privileges, working for Windows 7, 8, etc. Note that this won't display an UAC popup on Windows startup "Are you sure to run this software with Admin rights?", that's why the Task Scheduler method is more interesting in this case than the good old HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\...\CurrentVersion\Run solution)

There are a few things to update in [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381911(v=VS.85).aspx)
to make it work:

- [`_variant_t(L"S-1-5-32-544")`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7791481/1422096) instead of `_variant_t(L"Builtin\\Administrators")`
- [_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22450838/1422096)
- In VC++, Project Properties > Configuration Properties > Linker > Manifest file > UAC Execution Level > requireAdministrator
- Remove the date boundaries which are now outdated !
- Replace `hr = pLogonTrigger->put_UserId(_bstr_t(L"DOMAIN\\UserName"));` by either a hardcoded Domain\Username, or by some [Domain\Username detection code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724435(v=vs.85).aspx) (I couldn't make it work), or **just comment this line**, it worked for me!
- Add some code for `TASK_RUNLEVEL_HIGHEST`
- Add some code to enable the task **even if running from a laptop on batteries** (default would be "don't run task if on batteries"!), and some code to prevent the .exe to be killed after some time ([By default, a task will be stopped 72 hours after it starts to run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381850(v=vs.85).aspx)), etc.

Then you'll get the famous:

> Success! Task successfully registered.

---

Phew! After a few hours per day and some edits, now here is a working full `main.cpp`:

```
#define SECURITY_WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <Security.h>
#include <taskschd.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "taskschd.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "comsupp.lib")

using namespace std;

#define TASKNAME L"Logon Trigger Test Task"

int __cdecl wmain()
{
    //  Get the windows directory and set the path to notepad.exe.
    wstring wstrExecutablePath = _wgetenv(L"WINDIR");
    wstrExecutablePath += L"\\SYSTEM32\\NOTEPAD.EXE";

    //  Initialize COM  
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hr)) return 1;

    //  Set general COM security levels.
    hr = CoInitializeSecurity(NULL, -1, NULL, NULL, RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_PRIVACY, RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, NULL, 0, NULL);
    if (FAILED(hr)) goto cleanup0;

    //  Create an instance of the Task Service.     
    ITaskService *pService = NULL;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_TaskScheduler, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_ITaskService, (void**)&pService);
    if (FAILED(hr)) goto cleanup0;

    //  Connect to the task service.    
    hr = pService->Connect(_variant_t(), _variant_t(), _variant_t(), _variant_t());
    if (FAILED(hr)) goto cleanup1;

    //  Get the pointer to the root task folder.  This folder will hold the new task that is registered.
    ITaskFolder *pRootFolder = NULL;
    hr = pService->GetFolder(_bstr_t(L"\\"), &pRootFolder);
    if (FAILED(hr)) goto cleanup1;

    //  If the same task exists, remove it. 
    pRootFolder->DeleteTask(_bstr_t(TASKNAME), 0);

    //  Create the task builder object to create the task.  
    ITaskDefinition *pTask = NULL;
    hr = pService->NewTask(0, &pTask);

    // COM clean up.  Pointer is no longer used.    
    pService->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr)) { pRootFolder->Release(); CoUninitialize(); return 1; }

    //  Get the registration info for setting the identification.   
    IRegistrationInfo *pRegInfo = NULL;
    hr = pTask->get_RegistrationInfo(&pRegInfo);
    if (FAILED(hr)) goto cleanup2;

    hr = pRegInfo->put_Author(L"Author Name");
    pRegInfo->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr)) goto cleanup2;

    //  Create the settings for the task
    ITaskSettings *pSettings = NULL;
    hr = pTask->get_Settings(&pSettings);
    if (FAILED(hr)) goto cleanup2;
    
    //  Set setting values for the task. 
    pSettings->put_DisallowStartIfOnBatteries(VARIANT_FALSE);
    pSettings->put_StopIfGoingOnBatteries(VARIANT_FALSE);
    pSettings->put_ExecutionTimeLimit(_bstr_t(L"PT0S"));
    pSettings->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr)) goto cleanup2;

    //  Get the trigger collection to insert the logon trigger.
    ITriggerCollection *pTriggerCollection = NULL;
    hr = pTask->get_Triggers(&pTriggerCollection);
    if (FAILED(hr)) goto cleanup2;

    //  Add the logon trigger to the task.
    ITrigger *pTrigger = NULL;
    hr = pTriggerCollection->Create(TASK_TRIGGER_LOGON, &pTrigger);
    pTriggerCollection->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr)) goto cleanup2;

    ILogonTrigger *pLogonTrigger = NULL;
    hr = pTrigger->QueryInterface(IID_ILogonTrigger, (void**)&pLogonTrigger);
    pTrigger->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr)) goto cleanup2;

    hr = pLogonTrigger->put_Id(_bstr_t(L"Trigger1"));
    if (FAILED(hr)) goto cleanup2;

    //  Define the user.  The task will execute when the user logs on. The specified user must be a user on this computer.  
    //hr = pLogonTrigger->put_UserId(_bstr_t(L"DOMAIN\\UserName"));

    pLogonTrigger->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr)) goto cleanup2;

    IPrincipal *pPrincipal;
    hr = pTask->get_Principal(&pPrincipal);
    if (FAILED(hr)) goto cleanup2;

    hr = pPrincipal->put_RunLevel(TASK_RUNLEVEL_HIGHEST);
    if (FAILED(hr)) goto cleanup2;


    //  Add an Action to the task. This task will execute .exe
    IActionCollection *pActionCollection = NULL;

    //  Get the task action collection pointer.
    hr = pTask->get_Actions(&pActionCollection);
    if (FAILED(hr)) goto cleanup2;

    //  Create the action, specifying that it is an executable action.
    IAction *pAction = NULL;
    hr = pActionCollection->Create(TASK_ACTION_EXEC, &pAction);
    pActionCollection->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr)) goto cleanup2;

    //  QI for the executable task pointer.
    IExecAction *pExecAction = NULL;
    hr = pAction->QueryInterface(IID_IExecAction, (void**)&pExecAction);
    pAction->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr)) goto cleanup2;

    //  Set the path of the executable.
    hr = pExecAction->put_Path(_bstr_t(wstrExecutablePath.c_str()));
    pExecAction->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr)) goto cleanup2;

    //  Save the task in the root folder.
    IRegisteredTask *pRegisteredTask = NULL;
    hr = pRootFolder->RegisterTaskDefinition(_bstr_t(TASKNAME), pTask, TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE, _variant_t(L"S-1-5-32-544"), _variant_t(), TASK_LOGON_GROUP, _variant_t(L""), &pRegisteredTask);      //_variant_t(L"Builtin\\Administrators"),
    if (FAILED(hr)) goto cleanup2;

    printf("Success! Task successfully registered.");
    getchar();

    pRootFolder->Release();
    pTask->Release();
    pRegisteredTask->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;

cleanup0:
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;

cleanup1:
    pService->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;

cleanup2:
    pRootFolder->Release();
    pTask->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;
}
```